# Rotate a bones without rigging meshes

Tags: rigging

When creating the skeleton, I did not notice that the bones have an incorrect rotation of the coordinate axes. Now I have a skeleton with attached body parts. How can I rotate the bones without touching the meshes? Now if I rotate a bone (Ctrl+R) in Edit mode, parts of the body also turn into Pose and Object modes.

[image]

1. What i have. Wrong coordinates.
2. What i want to have
3. What do I get if I rotate the bones. The attached parts of the body also rotate.

What can i do?

Comment: clear parent then rotate and then parent again?

Comment: @Viplav Prakash but how can I save all the bone properties that I made? Now I have many modifiers responsible for the comfortable movement of the character

Comment: if you rotate in Edit mode it should not rotate In Pose mode... maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/